# Does it make sense to convert regexps to imperative code or the other way around?

Tags: regex

I'm writing a language parser, and some of the parsing is done by iterative operations (like "if the next character is `"` do this, and if the next two characters are `\"` then do something else).

Additionally, other operations I now match via regular expressions, for example if the next few characters match expression `/\([^(]+\)/`, then do something.

And I'm wondering, what is the best of these two? Should I use regular expressions for everything in the parsing? Or maybe I should rewrite `/\([^(]+\)/` into imperative code? Would the compile time for regular expressions, and then regexp engine match be better than imperative code?

What do you consider when making a decision like that? Should I even care about that?

Comment: I don't think the difference in perf will be so noticeable if you have to rewrite the imperative code for the regex, but to parse languages something like Antlr should be much better and powerful than regex

Comment: It depends on the programming language. If you are programming in a rather low-level, compiled language, like C, it doesn't really matter. If however you are programming in a higher level, interpreted language, like Python, you often get better results by doing as much as possible in single operations, so if you have an efficient regex, then certainly go for that instead of doing it character by character in a loop.